# How do I pass cxxflags to Boost libraries from within my jamfile?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, dependencies, bjam

I have a project with some requirements, one of which is to set the c++11 compiler/linker flags:

**jamroot.jam:**

```
project
    : requirements
      <toolset>clang:<cxxflags>"-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11"
      <toolset>clang:<linkflags>"-lc++"
      # ... etc
    ;

lib mylibrary
    : #sources
        [ glob source/*.cpp ]
        /boost/filesystem
        /boost/system
        /boost/thread//boost_thread
    ;
```

The library-specific sources *are* being compiled with the necessary c++11 flags, however the Boost libraries mentioned *do not*. This is causing no end of binary incompatibilities and linker errors.

I do not want to specify the `cxxflags` explicitly in either the user-config or the command line. I would like to make sure the jamroot/jamfiles are all that is necessary to build the project properly.

How do I "pass in" the desired `cxxflags` to the dependent Boost libraries?

**Update**: I recently tried using an `alias` to accomplish my goal. From [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/bbv2/tasks.html#bbv2.tasks.alias):

> Another use of the alias rule is to change build properties. For example, if you want to use link statically to the Boost Threads library, you can write the following:
>
> ```
> alias threads : /boost/thread//boost_thread : <link>static ;
> ```

However setting this up for `boost_filesystem` and rebuilding, say, `path.cpp` still omits the properties I am trying to build with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by [setting up a feature](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.build/26077) (thanks to Steven Watanabe):

```
feature.feature cpp11 :
    on :
    composite optional propagated
    ;

feature.compose <cpp11>on :
        <cxxflags>"-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11"
        <define>BOOST_NO_CXX11_NUMERIC_LIMITS=1
        <linkflags>"-lc++"
    ;

project
    : requirements
      <cpp11>on
      # ... etc
    ;
```

Apparently this is the only way to get variables to propagate to dependent libraries.